# Make mouse ignore microsecond clicks

Tags: windows-7, mouse, windows-registry

I've had issues with my mouse so I decided to figure out its problem. The symptom was that multiple clicks were recorded when only one was meant. I found out that the problem was the mechanical switch since an electronic switch like a Schmitt trigger would not be used in a cheap mouse. So there are microscopic signals jumping across even if there is no physical contact.

I think the problem would disappear if two (or multiple) clicks were ignored if they happened faster than 0.1 seconds, I probably wouldn't click faster than that so the functionality wouldn't be compromised. If say two clicks happened within 0.01 second they would be interpreted as one.

The only option in the Control Panel I see concerns double-click speed when opening a directory so I looked into the registry.

[image]

Would any of them do it?

Comment: What mouse model this is? I know Minecraft players are always looking for such hardware by purpose..

Comment: It's logitech m90.